# Is there any way to use unlink(__file__) in eval PHP

Tags: php, eval

I want to use `unlink(__file__)` in eval. As like

```
<?php
eval(base64_decode('dW5saW5rKF9fZmlsZV9fKTs='));
?>
```

But this code is not working. Is there any way to delete file itself with eval?

Comment: Welcome. "_As like_" where does `unlink(__file__)` appear in that code? Also please explain what "_is not working_" means

Comment: @kerbholz unlink is that base64 encoded string

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting set to `E_ALL`. If you run the script through a web server, check the error log. You can also enable display errors while developing to get errors directly. If the unlink() fails, it should throw some warning

Comment: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\unlink.php(2) : eval()'d code on line 1  This error displaying

Comment: So you want a script that deletes itself? is that right?

Comment: Yes. I wanna delete it